# user presses back button on device (emulator) control

Tags: android, emulation

Is there any way to control the previous activity when the user presses the back button on the device.

Controlling it by setting a TextView to clear when the user does or ending the previous activity.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course!  Android provides some build in methods that are invoked when events (like pressing the back button and going to a previous activity) take place.  These methods are detailed in the [Android Activity life cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

One way to solve your problem would be by using the onResume method.  Inside this method you can set your TextView to whatever you want once the activity is resumed.

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //now perform any operations on your textview
    //for example
    fooTextView.setText("I resumed my activity");
}
```

One side note, is this code will get fired as the user starts the Activity for the first time.  You may need to prevent this happening via a boolean value or use an alternative method to solve your problem like the method `onActivityResult` if you feel it is appropriate.